# cherry tree not flowering and not leafing out

Tags: fruit-trees

I live in North California and my cherry tree is not leafing out and not flowering. Below are the photos of the tree.

[image]

All the others trees in my backyard and most trees in my neighbors have already produced leaves. When I scratch a branch, it still shows the green color so I guess it is alive. I am wondering what could prevent a tree from leafing out.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The buds seem healthy (picture in the middle), so I think it could be one of the two (or both):

- you plant is in a really cold place (micro climate), maybe because of wind patters because of houses and trees or underground pipes.
- it is a variety for later fruits (or just of warmer climate), so the tree starts blooming later.

You can wait few weeks. You can help to gain a week or so, on putting leaves on ground in fall. As far I know, the "temperature sensor" in plants are in the roots.

Answer (score 2):

You Cherry tree looks healthy. Don't scratch too much branches on that little one. Maybe you could stack a little much around it (not too close to the trunk), because the earth looks rocky and poor.

- This is clearly going to bloom very soon. No worries.